# MongoDB sacar informacion y crear objeto

Tags: java, mongodb

```
    public void BuscarPorfecha(String fecha) {
    BOE boe = new BOE();
    List<BOE> lista = new ArrayList<BOE>();
    int i = 0;
    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(eq("fecha", fecha)).iterator();
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next().toJson());
        }
    }
```

Como podria crear un objeto a partir del cursor.next().toJson()??

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con `objeto`? ¿A envolverlo en una clase?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un objeto directamente a partir de cursor.next():

```
    Document document = cursor.next();
```